# is ts-jest using the same target from typescript compiler?

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a small Node project with TS where I'm trying to write a test that instantiates one model but I'm getting this error:

TypeError: Class constructor Project cannot be invoked without 'new'

```
  12 |
  13 |   test('it list all projects', async function () {
> 14 |     const project = new Project();
```

In the App code, the instantiation happens without any problem, but running this test I'm getting this error. Can someone help me to understand what is wrong here?

My Environment:
node: 16.14.0
typescript: 4.5.2
jest: 27.5.1
ts-jest: 27.1.4

I've tried to change the global ts-jest options but no success.

Comment: Can you show the code of the `Project`?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. That's my small project code: https://github.com/rogeraraujo90/heyfreela-api

You'll notice in `projects.test.ts` that I'm not using the class instantiation. If I change the code to use `new Project` instead, the error happens.